# Skeleton CSS Grid Framework Design Goals?

Tags: css, layout, html, accessibility

I like [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) but I have a few questions:

- Why use pixel sizes when it could all be achieved using relative/em sizes?
- Is this because it's the only reliable way to achieve x-browser compatibility? .. as using em sizes feels more appropriate / future proof
- Does relative sizing and reactive grid design really matter given that most browser are pretty smart at zooming now and people can just set their default zoom level?

Didn't want to decompose this into separate questions because Im trying to get the professional community's high level view of this framework's (mis)use of CSS best practices.

Finally if you have alternatives that you think tackle things more appropriately, do please share (with reasons!).

Comment: thanks updated a few, still consider this open for now though

Answer (score 2):

Pixel sizes still matter: 960 pixels wide is quite a standard, iPad landscape width is 1024px, etc... It seems that a webpage width of about 1000px is becoming a defacto standard for simple content website (makes sense when some screens can stretch a good 1900 or 2400px wide)... These width can not be expressed through em, because em is not fixed by definition. Em has its use when you're inside a fixed-sized frame and you want to space elements relatively to the font you choose.

Very few people can use their browser's zoom, and even fewer people bother to change the default zoom value. So you should aim for the most standard, ie 1000px wide, and they will cope with it.

Comment: Yeah and skeleton's handling of the media queries is exceptional, so it knows the pixel ranges it's working in at any given time. Are you saying that em/ex would be too imprecise even when the pixel sizes are known because of the different browser rendering models?